# Writing a method that simply multiplies the object by something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to convert a bunch of numbers from imperial to metric on the front end of my site depending on if the user has set their measurement_units to 'metric' or 'imperial'

I can just do `@myWeight*.45` to convert the number, but what I want to do is write a helper method like this

```
def is_imperial?
  if User.measurement_units == 'metric'
    *0.453592
  elsif User.measurement_units == 'imperial'
    *1
  end
end
```

then be able to do this: `@myWeight*.is_imperial?`

I'm just not sure how I would assign the `*value` to the method `is_imperial?`

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

@myWeight is a float calculated from adding several numbers.

I'm just trying to find an elegant way of converting any number that shows up on the site to metric if the user has metric as the value in the `measurement_units` field on the User model.

I assumed I would need to create a helper method in the application_helper.rb. Is that not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `measurement_units` method to be dynamic based on the user, then I think you need to make it an instance method.

Modify the `is_imperial?` method to return the right number:

```
def is_imperial?
  if measurement_units == 'metric'
    0.453592
  elsif measurement_units == 'imperial'
    1
  end
end
```

Then you can call the method with something like this:

```
@myWeight.send(:*, is_imperial?)
```

If @myWeight represents a `User` object you might have to change it to this:

```
@myWeight.weight.send(:*, is_imperial?)
```

Methods that end with a ? in Ruby are expected to return true or false, so you should rename the method to be something like weight_conversion_factor.

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Where is the best place for this? The `application_helper.rb` file? I want to use it across my app. I'm getting a no method error when I try to call `User.measurement_units` any idea why? `current_user.measurement_units` works in the view.

Comment: `measurment_units` is an instance method, so it works on instances of the `User` class (i.e. `current_user`).  When you call `User.measurement_units` you get an error because `measurement_units` is not a class method.  I made a quiz that might help you with OOP: http://www.codequizzes.com/topics/24/quizzes/79.  And yes, if you would like to use this method in the views across your app, the `application_helper.rb` file is the best place :)

Comment: That explanation and quiz was really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean something like this:

```
class User

  def imperial
    f_multiplier = 0.0
    f_multiplier = !!(self.measurement_units == 'metric') ? 0.453592 : 1
    imperial = self.weight * f_multiplier
  end

end

puts @myWeight.imperial
```

Comment: I doubt that `@myWeight` is a User instance

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really give a more accurate answer without seeing the rest of the code he's using :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `@myWeight` is Float value, you seem like you are looking for how to monkey patch. Check in rails console, `@myWeight.class.name` returns Float.

For monkey patching in Rails,

Create `config/initializers/extensions` directory. This is where you will store any future monkey patched methods.

Create a file called, `floats.rb`.

Add the following code.

```rb
class Float
  def is_imperial?
    if User.measurement_units == 'metric'
      self*0.453592
    elsif User.measurement_units == 'imperial'
      self*1
    end
  end
end
```

Make sure to restart the Rails server to reinitialize.

Comment: Is monkey patching the proper way of doing this kind of thing? I'm really trying to figure out an elegant way of converting measurement units on the front end. The term monkey patch makes it sound like a hack or something.

Comment: Also, why wouldn't I want to put this as a method in the application_helper.rb file?

Comment: If you are looking for front end solution, I would look for javascript solution. If you are looking for Rails solution, and if @myWeight is Float value and you want to do `@myWeight.is_imperial?`, then yes, this is what you would do. It is very much a Ruby way. Ruby programmers monkey patch all the time and easy monkey patching is one of Ruby's strengths.

Comment: I haven't found a better place to put monkey patched code other than `config/initializers/extensions`. I just find it ugly to put monkey patched methods for String, Array, Float in anywhere in `app` directory